# Don't highlighte the cursor in the Codemirror when invoke find next in IE

Tags: javascript, css, codemirror

I use CodeMirror for highlighte xml. It makes search perfect, but when i try *find next* cursor not highlighted in IE8(in others version I have not tried).

Has anyone had similar problems?

It also does not work in the demo(Use IE8):

http://codemirror.net/demo/search.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing

```
    .CodeMirror-searching {
       border: 1px solid #E9D9D9;
       background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
    }
```

to

```
    .CodeMirror-searching {
      background-image : url(opacity.png);
    }
```

Where opacity.png is 25% opacity png 1x1px file